# Как 'растянуть' массив в python через numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Мне нужно растянуть большой массив, но простым циклом это будет довольно долго, numpy.pad() работает корректно только на массивах размера 2 на 2.
например, массив:

```
[[ 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [ 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [ 9,10,11,12],
 [13,14,15,16]]
```

мне нужно преобразовать в

```
[[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
 [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
 [ 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8],
 [ 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8],
 [ 9, 9,10,10,11,11,12,12],
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Примените последовательно np.repeat к строкам и столбцам или в обратном порядке

```
new_arr = np.repeat(arr, 2, axis=1)
new_arr = np.repeat(new_arr, 2, axis=0)
print(new_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться библиотеками для обработки изображений, OpenCV или Pillow, должно работать быстро:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
a=np.array([[ 1, 2, 3, 4],[ 5, 6, 7, 8],[ 9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
m,n=a.shape
result=cv2.resize(a,(2*m,2*n), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```